# Can't read cookies through PHP or Javascript when on an iPad

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ipad, mobile

I am currently having a few issues when trying to read cookies using PHP or Javascript. I have tried using:

```
if(!$_COOKIE['popup_closed']
&& !isset($_COOKIE['username'])
&& !isset($_COOKIE['password'])
)
```

And I have tried:

```
if(
$.cookie('popup_closed') == null
&& $.cookie('username') == null
&& $.cookie('password') == null) {
doStuff();
}
```

(Using the jquery.cookie plugin)

And neither of them work on iPad. It works on all browsers fine, I have tried Googling the issue but there dosen't seem to be much information on reading cookies on an iPad.

Thanks for any help you guys can give!

Comment: Does your code work fine on Safary (on Mac or PC)? It should work identically on iPad.

Comment: It does indeed. And Cookies are turned on on the iPad too.

Comment: unfortunately I have no idea why it doesn't work, but some time ago I had problem related to cookies on all Safari version (Mac, PC, iPad etc). It was the built-in restriction of Safari (Safari doesn't accept cookies from 3rd party sites unless the user explicitly interacted with the web page). Maybe you're trying to use cookies from iframe?

Comment: Well I guess the issue isn't with the cookie technically, it is with checking if one is there or not, which seems to be the first hurdle.

Comment: You're right. All the information I could find was your standard, "How to accept cookies", "How to read and write cookies", etc. In fact this question is the _only_ thing I can find. :) Maybe you can take it up with Apple's support staff and post the answer here.

Answer (score 7):

This is really a workaround, but you could use the local storage if it's available - atleast I've used it in iPad/iPhone successfully.

For example with this kind of solution.

```
function saveData(name, value) {
    if (typeof(localStorage) != 'undefined') {
        localStorage.setItem(name, value);
    } else {
        createCookie(name, value, 7);
    }
}

function loadData(name) {
    var temp_value = '';

    if (typeof(localStorage) != 'undefined') {
        temp_value = localStorage.getItem(name);
    } else {
        temp_value = readCookie(name);
    }

    return temp_value;
}

function eraseData(name) {
    if (typeof(localStorage) != 'undefined') {
        localStorage.removeItem(name);
    } else {
         eraseCookie(name);
    }

}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";

    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        } 
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for this! I will see if it works next Tuesday as that is the day I work on the site in question. I will accept your answer on Tuesday if it works :) Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, no problem, good to hear the solution was useful for you!

Comment: If the user has cookies disabled, localstorage won't work too. And there's no serverside check for localstorage

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) regarding setcookie? You should use all variables, perhaps this solves the fact that you cannot access your cookies with JS? Also, using native JS to access the cookies (instead of jQuery), doesn't that work?